# asymptotics of sum of $\ln$

Tags: calculus

Let $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be sequences of complex numbers such that: $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|z_n|=+\infty$, $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|u_n|=+\infty$, $|u_n|=o(|z_n|)$ and $(|u_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is non-decreasing. I want to prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln|z_n-u_k|\underset{n\to+\infty}{\sim} n\ln|z_n|.$$

I did not manage to prove that. Any proof or hint will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|u_n|=o(|z_n|)$ for $n\to \infty$ and since $|u_k|$ is non-decreasing, we have for sufficiently large $n$ and $k\le n$

$$\left|\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\le 1/2 \tag1$$

With $n\ge k$ chosen so that $(1)$ holds, application of the triangle inequality reveals

$$\frac12\le 1-\left|\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right| \le \left|1-\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\le 1+\left|\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\le \frac32\tag 2$$

---

Now, write the summand, $\log\left(\left|z_n-u_k\right|\right)$, as

$$\log(|z_n-u_k|)=\log(|z_n|)+\log\left(\left|1-\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\right)\tag 3$$

we find that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(\left|z_n-u_k\right|\right)\right|&=n\log(|z_n|)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|\log\left(\left|1-\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\right)\right|\\\\
&\le n\log(|z_n|)+n\log(2)\\\\
&\sim n\log(|z_n|)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Can you explain the inequality $\left|\ln\left|1-\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{u_k}{z_n}\right|$ ?

Comment: Yes.  It's easy to show that $|1-z|\le 1+|z|$.  And we also have $\log(1+x)\le x$

Comment: but $\log(x)$ can be "very" negative, so the absolute value would be "very" positive

Comment: I don't know what "very negative" and "very positive" mean.  But the estimates are correct and in the posted answer, I used magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I had misread the question. For any $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,$ $|u_n/z_n| < \epsilon,$ and the same is true for all $k\leq n,$ by monotonicity. So, 
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log |z_n - u_k| - n \log|z_n|\right| =
\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(1-\frac{u_k}{z_n}) \right|\leq n\epsilon.$$
Now, divide through by $n\log |z_n|$ to get 
$$\frac{\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log |z_n - u_k|\right|}{n \log|z_n|}-1\leq \epsilon/|z_n|\leq \epsilon,$$for $n>N,$ and also large enough so that $|z_n|>1.$

Comment: Your $u_n$ doesn't satisfy the conditions though?

Comment: @Jack ok, let $u_n = 2^n.$

Comment: Yeah, that satisfies the conditions. Why doesn't it satisfy the asymptotic relation? (Not doubting you - just can't see it myself).

Comment: @igorrivin And how does $u_n=2^n$ and $z=2{2^n}$ show that the proposed asymptotic expression is false?

Comment: @MarkViola I did *not* say $z_n = 22^n.$ In what I did say, $\sum_{I=1}^n \log (2^{2^n} -  2^n) \sim \log 2 \sum 2^n \sim \log 2 2^{n+1} \ll n 2^n,$ where the last is what the OP suggests.

Comment: @IgorRivin the sum is over $k$, so $\sum 2^n=n2^n$ and it is OK, isn't it?

Comment: @igorrivin That was a typographical error.  I meant $2^{2^n}$, which is precisely what you wrote.  And the analysis in your comment is fatally flawed.  $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^n=n2^n\ne 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @joaopa Yes, I read your question incorrectly.

Comment: @MarkViola I misread the OP's question. Fatally flawed????

Comment: @Mark Viola > Where is your answer? Looks like it disappeared.

Comment: @joaopa I'll fix it tomorrow.  It's time to sleep.

Comment: @Igor In your first equality, it is missing an absolute value wrapping the $(1-\frac{u_k}{z_n})$ that complicates the  thing.

Comment: @joaopa No, it does not complicate anything, it's just a typo.